# MeteorCollection retrieves results every other time

Tags: ios, swift, meteor

I am using the [SwiftDDP](https://github.com/siegesmund/SwiftDDP)/Swift 2.3 with a Meteor/Mongo backend. Navigating from one view to another only gets me results **every other time**.

Here is a visual flow of my issue:

Click on comments button/link

[image]

Get results and they respond to updates from the db! woo!

[image]

Go back to comments button/link via back button in header and click again

[image]

Empty results! I am able to repeat these same steps with the same results without restarting the debugger.

[image]

**My model**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftDDP

class Comment: MeteorDocument {
    var collection: String = "comments"
    var id: String?
    var body: String?
    var userId: String?
    var postId: String?
    var createdAt: NSDate?
    var userObj: User?
}
```

**Viewcontroller**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import SwiftDDP

class CommentViewController: NavigableViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    //-- via AppDelegate.swift:
    //-- let comments = MeteorCollection<Comment>(name: "comments")
    var comments:MeteorCollection<Comment> = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).comments

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //-- connect to "comments" model
        comments = MeteorCollection<Comment>(name: "comments")

        //-- subscribe to postsComments meteor method on the server
        Meteor.subscribe("postsComments", params: [["postId": self.source!.id!]]) {
            self.createView()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

**ViewControllerUI**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import SwiftDDP


extension CommentViewController {
    func createView() {

        //-- Use CommentTableViewCell for cell class
        self.tableView.registerClass(CommentTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CommentTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier)

       self.makeHeader()
       self.makeContentArea()

        //-- Sign up the view to receive Meteor updates
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(CommentViewController.reloadTableView), name: METEOR_COLLECTION_SET_DID_CHANGE, object: nil)


    }

func makeHeader() {
        header = UIView()
        header.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        self.view.addSubview(header)
        header.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.top.equalTo(self.view)
            make.left.equalTo(self.view)
            make.right.equalTo(self.view)
            make.height.equalTo(65)
        }

        let nameLabel = UILabel()
        header.addSubview(nameLabel)
        nameLabel.text = "Comments".localize()
        nameLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        nameLabel.font = Font.mediumBold
        nameLabel.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.top.equalTo(header).offset(34)
            make.centerX.equalTo(header)
        }


        let backButton = UIButton()
        backButton.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        let backImage = UIImage(named: "ic_back")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
        backButton.setImage(backImage, forState: .Normal)
        header.addSubview(backButton)
        backButton.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.left.equalTo(header).offset(4)
            make.centerY.equalTo(nameLabel)
            make.height.equalTo(25)
            make.width.equalTo(25)
        }
        backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapBack), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    }

    func makeContentArea() {
        let content = UIView()
        self.view.addSubview(content)
        content.backgroundColor = Color.vcBackgroundColor
        content.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.top.equalTo(65)
            make.left.equalTo(self.view)
            make.right.equalTo(self.view)
            make.height.equalTo(self.view)
        }

        //-- TableView for comment list
        let contentTableView = UITableView(frame: content.frame)
        content.addSubview(contentTableView)
        contentTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.tableView = contentTableView
        contentTableView.delegate = self
        contentTableView.dataSource = self


        contentTableView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.top.equalTo(content)
            make.left.equalTo(content)
            make.right.equalTo(content)
            make.height.equalTo(content).inset(65)
        }

        let commentInput = CustomTextField()
        self.commentInput = commentInput
        commentInput.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        commentInput.textField.placeholder = "Write a comment...".localize()
        content.addSubview(commentInput)
        commentInput.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.bottom.equalTo(content).inset(75)
            make.left.equalTo(content)
            make.right.equalTo(content)
            make.height.equalTo(35)
        }
    }
}
```

**Table Delegate**

```
import UIKit

extension CommentViewController {
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.comments.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CommentTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        if let card = cell as? CommentTableViewCell {
            let item = self.comments.sorted[indexPath.row]
            card.populate(item)
        }

        return CommentTableViewCell()
    }

    func reloadTableView() {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

**CommentTableViewCell**

```
import UIKit

class CommentTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, ContextLabelDelegate {
    var data:Comment!
    var profilePicture:UIImageView!
    var commentLabel:UILabel!

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
        self.createView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func createView() {
        profilePicture = UIImageView()
        profilePicture.backgroundColor = Color.darkGrey
        self.addSubview(profilePicture)
        profilePicture.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
        profilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(45 / 2)
        profilePicture.clipsToBounds = true

        profilePicture.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.top.equalTo(self).offset(12)
            make.left.equalTo(self).offset(12)
            make.width.equalTo(45)
            make.height.equalTo(45)
        }

        commentLabel = UILabel()
        commentLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        commentLabel.backgroundColor = Color.offwhite
        commentLabel.font = Font.smallLight
        self.addSubview(commentLabel)
        commentLabel.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.top.equalTo(self).offset(12)
            make.left.equalTo(65)
            make.width.equalTo(self).offset(-80)
            make.bottom.equalTo(45)
        }


    }

    func populate(data: Comment) {
        self.data = data

        MeteorAPI.sharedInstance.getUserProfile(data.userId!) { (user) in

            if let profileImage = user.profile?.picture {
                let nsUrl = NSURL(string: profileImage)
                self.profilePicture.af_setImageWithURL(nsUrl!)
            } else {
                let nsUrl = NSURL(string: "https://placekitten.com/g/200/300")
                self.profilePicture.af_setImageWithURL(nsUrl!)
            }
        }

        commentLabel.text = "This is a test comment. It's going to be yuge! Some other comments like this will be great, but mine will be the best!"


    }

    static var reuseIdentifier: String {
        get {
            return "CommentTableViewCell"
        }
    }
}
```

Including the custom NavigableViewController here. I don't **think** it's part of the problem, but didn't want to leave it out.

```
class NavigableViewController: UIViewController {

    func pushView(viewController: UIViewController) {
        self.addChildViewController(viewController)
        self.view.addSubview(viewController.view)

        viewController.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
        viewController.view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5, -4)
        self.viewWillDisappear(true)
        viewController.viewWillAppear(true)
        self.animateFromTheRight(viewController)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.view.layoutSubviews()
            }) { (finished) -> Void in }

    }

    func popView(viewController: UIViewController) {
        viewController.view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-5, -4)

        viewController.viewWillDisappear(true)
        self.viewWillAppear(true)

        self.animateToTheRight(viewController)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.view.layoutSubviews()
            }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
                viewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
                viewController.removeFromParentViewController()
        })
    }

    /**
     Is Called when the Current VC Index is lower than the VC to be shown index

     - parameter vc: The VC To be presented
     */
    func animateFromTheRight(vc: UIViewController) {
        vc.view.snp_makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(self.view)
            make.left.equalTo(self.view.snp_right)
            make.bottom.equalTo(self.view)
            make.width.equalTo(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width)
        }
        vc.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        self.view.layoutSubviews()
        vc.view.snp_remakeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(self.view)
            make.left.equalTo(self.view.snp_left)
            make.bottom.equalTo(self.view)
            make.width.equalTo(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width)
        }
    }

    func animateToTheRight(vc: UIViewController) {
        /*
        vc.view.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.top.equalTo(self.view)
            make.left.equalTo(self.view.snp_left)
            make.bottom.equalTo(self.view)
            make.width.equalTo(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width)
        }
         */
        self.view.layoutSubviews()
        vc.view.snp_remakeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.top.equalTo(self.view)
            make.left.equalTo(self.view.snp_right)
            make.bottom.equalTo(self.view)
            make.width.equalTo(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width)
        }
    }

}
```

**Logs from debugger**
On first comments click:

```
[Debug] [DDP] [DDP Background Data Queue :: NSOperation 0x61000025e9c0 (QOS: BACKGROUND)] [260] ddpMessageHandler > Received message: {
    collection = comments;
    fields =     {
        --fields redacted--
}
[Debug] [DDP] [DDP Background Data Queue :: NSOperation 0x60800025daf0 (QOS: BACKGROUND)] [260] ddpMessageHandler > Received message: {
    collection = comments;
    fields =     {
         --fields redacted--
}
[Debug] [DDP] [DDP Background Data Queue :: NSOperation 0x610000442730 (QOS: BACKGROUND)] [260] ddpMessageHandler > Received message: {
    msg = ready;
    subs =     (
        4799450060338752685
    );
}
```

**Logs upon clicking back button**

```
[Debug] [DDP] [DDP Background Data Queue :: NSOperation 0x618000447e60 (QOS: BACKGROUND)] [260] ddpMessageHandler > Received message: {
    collection = comments;
    id = 58899570593460ce53ca338c;
    msg = removed;
}
[Debug] [DDP] [DDP Background Data Queue :: NSOperation 0x60800025fda0 (QOS: BACKGROUND)] [260] ddpMessageHandler > Received message: {
    collection = comments;
    id = 58899577593460ce53ca338d;
    msg = removed;
}
[Debug] [DDP] [DDP Background Data Queue :: NSOperation 0x610000441aa0 (QOS: BACKGROUND)] [260] ddpMessageHandler > Received message: {
    id = 4799450060338752685;
    msg = nosub;
}
[Debug] [DDP] [DDP Background Data Queue :: NSOperation 0x618000445130 (QOS: BACKGROUND)] [260] ddpMessageHandler > Received message: {
    id = 4799450060338752685;
    msg = nosub;
}
```

**Logs on second comments click**

```
[Debug] [DDP] [DDP Background Data Queue :: NSOperation 0x6100004450a0 (QOS: BACKGROUND)] [260] ddpMessageHandler > Received message: {
    collection = comments;
    fields =     {
        --fields redacted--
    };
    id = 58899570593460ce53ca338c;
    msg = added;
}
[Debug] [DDP] [DDP Background Data Queue :: NSOperation 0x60800025db80 (QOS: BACKGROUND)] [260] ddpMessageHandler > Received message: {
    collection = comments;
    fields =     {
       --fields redacted--   
    };
    id = 58899577593460ce53ca338d;
    msg = added;
}
[Debug] [DDP] [DDP Background Data Queue :: NSOperation 0x618000448610 (QOS: BACKGROUND)] [260] ddpMessageHandler > Received message: {
    msg = ready;
    subs =     (
        4799450060338752685
    );
}
```